# Slider Not Excepting Current Default Value in Swift

Tags: function, swift, slider, calculator, updates

Sorry to do this again, but my code has yet ANOTHER problem.  When I run the program in the simulator, if I move the slider from its default position and hit the submit button, it will calculate the mpg.  However, if I leave the slider at its default position of 500, then choose how many gallons I used (like normal), and hit "Submit", I get a value of 0.0 for the mpg.  I know that it isn't right.  My instructor suggested that I put the values that were originally in the milesDrivenSliderValueChanged function and put them in their own function.  When I did, I got a bunch of errors.  I fixed them, but I still get the same results.  I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code for the slider and the new function it calls:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate
{
var BlopSoundURL =  NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Blop", ofType: "mp3")!)

var soundAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

var miles = 0.0
var gallonsUsed = 0.0
var mpg: Double = 0.0
var currentSelection: Double?

@IBOutlet weak var milesDrivenLabel: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var milesDrivenSlider: UISlider!

@IBAction func milesDrivenSliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider)
{
    currentSelection = Double(sender.value)

    sliderMoved()
}

func sliderMoved()
{
    milesDrivenLabel.text = "\(round(currentSelection! * 100) / 100)"
    println("Current Selection = \(currentSelection)")
    miles = currentSelection!
}
```

The rest of the code is for the Picker (which I don't think has any problems), the submit button, and the other functions:

```
@IBOutlet weak var gallonsUsedPicker: UIPickerView!
let pickerData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,
            12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,
            22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,
            32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,
            42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,
            52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,
            62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,
            72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,
            82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,
            92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100]

@IBAction func submitButton(sender: UIButton)
{
    soundAudioPlayer.play()
    let rowValue = gallonsUsedPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0) + 1
    gallonsUsed = Double(rowValue)

    mpg = Double(round((miles * 100) / gallonsUsed) / 100)

    let message = "Your MPG is approximately: \(mpg)."

    let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: "Your MPG",
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(
        title: "Ok",
        style: .Default,
        handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(action)
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return "\(row+1)"
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return 100
}


override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    gallonsUsedPicker.dataSource = self
    gallonsUsedPicker.delegate = self

    soundAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: BlopSoundURL, error: nil)


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}   // End of viewDidLoad
```

This is really frustrating.  It's probably a simple fix, but I just can't see it.  I spent 3 hours on this last night and 2 more hours just this morning.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you for your time and efforts.

Comment: `miles` will be zero until it is changed. It is only changed in your `sliderMoved()` function so it will be zero until you move the slider. You should set `miles` in the submit function as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a doofus.  I just had to change miles to 500, instead of zero.  Now it works.  Sorry, guys.